# I keep getting Error: int cannot be dereferenced. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, arrays, int, playing-cards

I am beginning to program War (the card game) and the methods have already been instantiated I need to know why I keep getting these errors.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CardGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CardDeck CardDeckA = new CardDeck();
        //creates a standard card deck with 52 cards 1 - 10, J, Q, K, A diamond, spade, club, heart


        //Card( int value, int suit)

        int[] player1 = new int[52];
        int[] player2 = new int[52];
        int a = player1.length;
        int b = player2.length;

        for (int i = 0; a <= 26; i++) {
            player1[i].deal(); //Error: int cannot be dereferenced
            //deal( int n):Deals n cards from the top of the CardDeck, returns Card[]
        }

        for (int j = 0; a <= 26; j++) {
            player2[j].deal();//Error: int cannot be dereferenced
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `ints` can't be dereferenced in Java. There is no such facility. You made it up. Too localized.

Comment: 2 errors found:
 Programs\CardGame\CardGame.java  [line: 14]
Error: int cannot be dereferenced
Programs\CardGame\CardGame.java  [line: 17]
Error: int cannot be dereferenced
@EJP how do I fix it then?

Comment: The deference operator is the dot (`.`) there. It cant be applied to an `int` as in you can do `int i = 0; i.THISISNOTRIGHT;`.

Comment: Also, your loops will go on forever, because `a` never changes, will remain `0`, and will never make `a <= 26` false.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the method as something like

```
player = CardDeckA.deal(1)
```

instead of

```
player1[i].deal()
```

since `player1[i]` is a primitive `int`, it does not have methods.

`deal` returns `int[]`, depending on how you use it, I suspect it would something similar to:

```
player = CardDeckA.deal(26)
```

Comment: `CardDeckA.deal(26)`.  By the way, `CardDeckA` is a bad name.  The original poster should just call it `deck`.

Comment: @EricJablow Ah, so many edits and still missed that `deal` is from a different object. The code in the original post is a bit beyond rescue unless we know what it is supposed to do:) Thanks!

Comment: Freshman magical thinking, I believe.  I had similar math students who tried to distribute square roots over addition because they forgot trigonometric substitutions.